# Highlight Current Page on DYnamic Navigation PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, content-management-system

I get my dynamic navigation menu from the database because I have a CMS, so here's my code:

```
<ul>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, DESCRIPTION FROM menu where VISIBLE='1' ORDER BY `order` ASC") or die(mysql_error());                   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
printf('<li>%s %s </a></li> ', $row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);
}
?>
```

to highlight the current page, i have to add this inside the li element

how should i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is what i have to put inside the li

Comment: You don't supply enough info.  What CMS?  Does it have a function that returns the current page?

Comment: <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>

Comment: this is what i have to put inside the li 
<li><?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="current"';?></li>

Answer (score 0):

u can try the following code

```
<?php 
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>

<ul>

<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, DESCRIPTION FROM menu where VISIBLE='1' ORDER BY
 `order` ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 ?>
<li<?php  if(preg_match("/index/i", $currentpage)||($currentpage=="/")) { echo " 
class='active'";     } ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>


<?
 }
?>
```

instead of index you can also write $row[name] in a variable and replace /index/i with it

Answer (score 0):

set a variable on the page like

```
$navlink = '<somevalue>'
```

and check the the value in li

```
<li <?php if($navlink == '<somevalue>') {echo "class='active'"}?>>
```

i think it will work.